# How do I copy tar files from User-mode Linux to the host?

Tags: linux, unix

I have some tar files inside a [User-mode Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux) distribution. I need to copy those files from a UML instance to the host.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Since you tagged the question [tag:linux], I assume you mean [User-mode Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux) and not [Unified Modeling Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language). Feel free to re-edit your post if this assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the UML docs?

> If you want to access files on the host machine from inside UML, you can treat it as a separate machine and either nfs mount directories from the host or copy files into the virtual machine with scp or rcp. However, since UML is running on the the host, it can access those files just like any other process and make them available inside the virtual machine without needing to use the network.

http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/old/UserModeLinux-HOWTO-9.html
http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/hostfs.html

There are some limitations but for a few files it should be simple enough.
If you're already ssh:ing to the guest and don't want do read new docs, regular scp/sftp is probably the most convenient.

Comment: Thank you very much micke. It has worked correctly, and now my files are safe. I have search all over the internet, and in the end, the answer was right in front of me. Shame on me.